# How to produce kafka message in JSON format using MongoDB Kafka Source Connector?

Tags: json, mongodb, converters, apache-kafka-connect

I'm getting confused reading document about MongoDB Kafka Connector's Converter. Can anybody answer at least one of my questions please...

1. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/v1.3/introduction/converters/#json-converter
   In this document, there's `StringConverter` and `JsonConverter`.
   What's the difference between them?? I wanna know input and output type of them.
2. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/v1.3/introduction/data-formats/#raw-json
   Here, it says

> You use Raw JSON when you specify a String converter on a source or sink connector.

so is that mean I should use StringConverter, not JsonConverter when I want to convert JSON string into JSON ?

3. What I wanna do is to produce a kafka message in a JSON format when a change event created in MongoDB. But it seems that native MongoDB Source Connector gives payload as a JSON string type, not JSON. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Did you figure out this? If yes then can you please share here. I am also not so much clear. Thank you !

@Broccoli_Salad

Comment: @SubhadipSahoo No Not yet.... :(